# Android: button showing up multiple times in list view

Tags: android, listview

I trying to write code to highlight the selected value of the list with "Next" button at the bottom of the layout. But for some reason, after every list item, "next" button also shows up. Can someone please help me resolve this problem?

Here is the layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/questionLayout"
    >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/txtExample"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listExample"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#CCCCCC"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
             android:id = "@+id/next"
             android:text="Next"
             android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
             android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:layout_weight="50"
        />
        <Button
             android:id = "@+id/submit"
             android:text="Submit"
             android:layout_width = "0dp"
             android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="50"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Java Code:

```
public class updateList extends Activity {

private SelectedAdapter selectedAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> list;
int correct_answer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Choice One");
    list.add("Choice Two");
    list.add("Choice Three");

    selectedAdapter = new SelectedAdapter(this,0,list);
    selectedAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);

    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listExample);
    listview.setAdapter(selectedAdapter);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {
            // user clicked a list item, make it "selected"
            selectedAdapter.setSelectedPosition(position);
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance
SSP

Selected Adaptor class:

```
public class SelectedAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

// used to keep selected position in ListView
private int selectedPos = -1;   // init value for not-selected

public SelectedAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                   List objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
}

public void setSelectedPosition(int pos){
    selectedPos = pos;
    // inform the view of this change
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public int getSelectedPosition(){
    return selectedPos;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    // only inflate the view if it's null
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    }

    // get text view
    TextView label = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtExample);

    // change the row color based on selected state
    if(selectedPos == position){
        label.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
    }else{
        label.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    label.setText(this.getItem(position).toString());

    /*
    // to use something other than .toString()
    MyClass myobj = (MyClass)this.getItem(position);
    label.setText(myobj.myReturnsString());
    */
    return(v);
}
}
```

Comment: I wonder if you set listView height to android:layout_height="fill_parent".Then how other layouts added below will be shown.Please confirm your code.

Comment: Changed it to "wrap_content" but still seeing same result.

Comment: @sathyapriya Use BaseAdapter instead of ArrayAdapter and Use custom listview in your application.

Answer (score 0):

change your listview in xml as like this

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/listExample"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"//===== set maximum heighthere
android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"//  === give some space at bottom so that buttons will appear
android:background="#CCCCCC"
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
  />
```

Comment: When I tried your suggestion, none of the choices showed up but button showed only once. Removing "layout_weight" took it to previous format

Answer (score 0):

> But for some reason, after every list item, "next" button also shows up.

The ListView's row layout is determined by the layout you inflate in `getView()` or pass to your Adapter's super class if you haven't overridden `getView()`. Double check this layout and remove the unwanted code.

---

**Addition**
The layout for your ListView's items only needs to be one TextView since you only want to display a phrase in each. However you are currently passing your entire main layout, this creates the Buttons, an unused ListView, and everthing else in *every* row...

Instead use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` in `getView()`, of course you'll need to change the id you pass to `findViewById()` as well:

```
if (v == null) {
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = vi.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
}

// get text view
TextView label = (TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
```

Please watch Android's Romain Guy discuss [writing an efficient adapter](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html) to speed things up.

Comment: Hi Sam, I have added getView() code to the original post. Is there a way to add the buttons programatically in getView(), I did some googling but unable to find any code.

Comment: I updated my answer. This will stop the Buttons from being display in every row. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for your help, I will try it out tomorrow and will update the post